# Convergence of $\sum \mathcal{O}(|a_n|^{k+1})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I conclude from the convergence of $\sum |a_n|^k$ the convergence of $\sum a_n^k$ and $\sum \mathcal{O}(|a_n|^{k+1})$?

For the first I suppose this is a direct result of the absolute convergence, but what about the second one? Can one prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_n=\mathcal{O}(|a_n|^{k+1})$. By definition, there exists $C>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|b_n|\leq C |a_n|^{k+1}$ for all $n\geq N$. Let $\epsilon>0$. There exists $N_0>N$ such that $\sum_{n\geq N_0} |a_n|^{k+1}<\epsilon.$

The sum can then split as $\sum_{n<N_0}b_n+\sum_{n\geq N_0}b_n$. Why is the last sum small?